# "she did have" or "she did has"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, subject-verb-agreement, do-support, emphasis

I just read this in a novel, and the sentence goes something like this

> Perhaps she ***did*** have asthma

Comment: When ***to do*** is used as an *auxiliary* verb (in your example, to provide emphasis over and above the simple statement *She had asthma*), you only inflect ***do*** for tense/number. The *primary* verb (***to have***, in this case) should be a simple ***infinitive*** form (but note that in such constructions we don't include the "infinitive marker" ***to***).

Comment: That is simply not true: Perhaps she did like to ride motorcycles.

Comment: @Lambie That auxiliary verb is connected to the primary verb "to like" not "to ride," so the statement is still completely true.

Answer (score 1):

**Auxiliary verbs in declarative sentences are used to emphasize the idea expressed by the verb, when the verb takes an auxiliary**. Emphasis for tenses where auxiliaries are part of the sentence is heard through intonation only.

1) Perhaps she **had** asmthma. → Perhaps she **did have** asthma.

2) They read a lot of books last summer. → They **did read** a lot of books last summer.

3) They'**ve been swimming** a lot lately. → They **have** been swimming a lot lately.

In cases like this,  the long form of the verb may be used  in writing but when speaking, the auxiliary is stressed more if one wants to emphasize the idea about swimming.

4) We'd love to see them tomorrow. → We **would** love to see them tomorrow.

Again, the *would* cannot be shortened if you are emphasizing this with intonation. Otherwise, one would most likely shorten it. We'd etc.
5) They **have** a huge house. →They **do have** a huge house.

Comment: Whoever has downvoted this doesn't know how English works. It's pathetic.

Answer (score 0):

While you may think

> She +**has** asthma.

should be together, that is the *present tense*. However, your sentence is in the *past tense*

> She **had** asthma.

When formed with **did** + *infinitive root* creates the *past

> She **did have** asthma.

Answer (score 0):

She did have. >>> You can only use the original form of the verb after the verb "do".

Grammatically, you can even say "she does do sth." >> Means "She indeed does sth."